# Obtaining a string in SQLITE3 before and after a certain Character

Tags: sqlite

I am working with SQLITE3. I am trying to chop an email address and display the Email Provider name without the .xxx at the end. So Something like abcd.kjhu@yahoo.co.nz will give me a result of 'yahoo'

I have seen some answers online that can chop whatever is after the @ sign but nothing that can take out the dots after that @ sign.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with SQLite3.

Comment: Look into the `substr()` and `instr()` functions. Or do it outside of sql; sqlite's builtin string search and manipulation functions are very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I found out The answer after all.

SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@')), 2, INSTR(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@')), '.') -2)) AS Provider

Thanks anyway everyone!